# Flask and Redis

Tags: python, flask, orm, redis

What is best way to interact with Redis in a Flask app? Do you just import Redis and ...

```
r = redis.Redis()
r.connect()
```

or is there an ORM or something I haven't seen yet?

Comment: This snippet on using Redis for server side sessions with Flask should be helpful: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/